# I have Next.js 13.4 web application written in typescript. How can I implement twilio's SMS feature in my application.This is my existing code snippet

Tags: typescript, twilio, sms, twilio-api, next.js13

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm2L2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6me79.png)This is my existing code snippet. I tried to alter JS code snippet.

I tried to alter JS code snippet into TS. But I unable to implement this. Using twilio SMS feature I am trying to implement OTP verification in my web application

Comment: The code itself seems right. Can you add more details what your question is or what isn't working as expected? Also, are you using the approuter or pages router of Next 13.4?